# How to detect process's highest cpu usage during it's life

Tags: monitoring, cpu, testing, cpu-usage

I've written some multi-thread test, and now I want to be sure that the highest CPU usage of this test is equal to `100 * CPU_NUMBER` of current machine. Is it possible to do?

UPD 0: I'm talking about Linux system.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229333/how-to-get-overall-cpu-usage-e-g-57-on-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you're looking for `sar`. SAR stands for System Activty Report. It's used in unix-like operating systems to report about CPU, memory and IO usage, collected by `sysstat`.

Then, `sysatat` can be configured to 
Monitor individual processes. [Link](https://www.google.it/amp/s/www.tecmint.com/sysstat-commands-to-monitor-linux/amp/)

How often it collects, and how long sar keeps reports is decided on the first setup.

You just want to note that such a data collection is not "free" so I won't keep it on on production servers.

After it is configured it will be easy for you to extract datas from reports in your script by using the `sar` command, `grep` and `awk`.

You didn't specified what OS are you working on, so I encourage you to search how to set up sar/sysstat on your distro.

Answer (score 3):

`pidstat` which is usually part of the `sysstat` package can monitor a single process id and print statistics on each of its threads. For example, for a running chrome browser:

```
$ pidstat -t -p 27680 1
17:17:36   TGID    TID    %usr %system  %guest    %CPU CPU  Command
17:17:37  27680      -   13.00    3.00    0.00   16.00   0  chrome
17:17:37      -  27680    9.00    1.00    0.00   10.00   0  |__chrome
17:17:37      -  27712    2.00    1.00    0.00    3.00   1  |__Chrome_IOThread
17:17:37      -  27714    2.00    0.00    0.00    2.00   1  |__CompositorTileW
```

This 1-second sample has many threads with 0% cpu which I have removed. I understand that 100% means just 1 cpu wholly occupied. There is a `-I` flag to divide this by the number of cpus.